# C++ Class Inheritance Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a thing with C++ where I'm making an object of abstract class Parent and initializing it in a function to a child class. When I initialize the object when it's created, everything works wonders. When I initialize it in a function, I get a segmentation fault.

Here's a code outline of what I'm doing

_class.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASS_H_INCLUDED

class Parent{
  public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Parent{
  public:
    virtual void foo(){
      ...
    }
};

class Child2 : public Parent{
  public:
    virtual void foo(){
      ...
    }
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "main.h"
#include "_class.h"

void setChild(Parent* c){
  c = new Child1();
}

int main() {
  Parent* c;// = new Child1();

  setChild(c);

  c->foo(); //Seg Fault
}
```

Obviously I could just initialize in main, but I'd rather initialize in the function. Is this possible, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Parent* c` passes a Parent by reference (specifically by a pointer), but the pointer itself is passed by value. `c` is a copy of the caller's argument and changes made to the copy are not duplicated at the caller. Use a reference : `void setChild(Parent* & c)`.

Comment: Pass a `Parent** p` to `setChild` and assign the result of `new Child1();` to `*p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the local `c` in `setChild` to a new object, but the one in `main` is not changed.  There are two ways to change the value in the caller.

One is to pass the parameter by reference:

```
void setChild(Parent*& c)
```

the other is to return it, rather than use a parameter

```
Parent *setChild() {
    return new Child1();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I hate C++. Defeated by an &. I'll accept your answer as soon as it allows me. Thank you.